# cannot resolve symbol TintSpinner

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library

I have a project in which we are using `TintSpinner`. But I am getting error as cannot resolve symbol `TintSpinner`, and unused import statement at the time of import . It is imported as:

```
import android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintSpinner;
```

I search in android docs but I am not getting this class. But I am getting source code [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/2ffab3d/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/internal/widget/TintSpinner.java).  How to remove this error. Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
public class TintSpinner extends Spinner {




private static final int[] TINT_ATTRS = {
    android.R.attr.background,
    android.R.attr.popupBackground
};
public TintSpinner(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}
public TintSpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, android.R.attr.spinnerStyle);
}
@SuppressLint("NewApi") public TintSpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    TintTypedArray a = TintTypedArray.obtainStyledAttributes(context, attrs, TINT_ATTRS,
            defStyleAttr, 0);
    setBackgroundDrawable(a.getDrawable(0));
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16 && a.hasValue(1)) {
        setPopupBackgroundDrawable(a.getDrawable(1));
    }
    a.recycle();
}
```

}

Add android-support-v7-appcompat.jar in your build path

Comment: If face any problem let me know. Please mark right if works. Also paste android-support-v4.jar in your lib in your project